# how to setState of an state array to new array in react Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

in my state i have a array .

```
this. state = {people : [] , show : false }
```

i am calling an api and receiving data. 
the received data is like some object inside an array . how can i setState the my initial array to this new array and show the data in UI by mapping one by one

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{name: "Luke Skywalker", height: "172", mass: "77", hair_color: "blond", skin_color: "fair", …}
1
:
{name: "C-3PO", height: "167", mass: "75", hair_color: "n/a", skin_color: "gold", …}
2
:
{name: "R2-D2", height: "96", mass: "32", hair_color: "n/a", skin_color: "white, blue", …}
3
:
{name: "Darth Vader", height: "202", mass: "136", hair_color: "none", skin_color: "white", …}
4
:
{name: "Leia Organa", height: "150", mass: "49", hair_color: "brown", skin_color: "light", …}
5
:
{name: "Owen Lars", height: "178", mass: "120", hair_color: "brown, grey", skin_color: "light", …}
6
:
{name: "Beru Whitesun lars", height: "165", mass: "75", hair_color: "brown", skin_color: "light", …}
7
:
{name: "R5-D4", height: "97", mass: "32", hair_color: "n/a", skin_color: "white, red", …}
8
:
{name: "Biggs Darklighter", height: "183", mass: "84", hair_color: "black", skin_color: "light", …}
9
:
{name: "Obi-Wan Kenobi", height: "182", mass: "77", hair_color: "auburn, white", skin_color: "fair", …}
length
:
10
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

///code this is the code of full component ....................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  View,
  Card,

} from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { fetchPeopleFromAPI } from './actions'



class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.state = { peoples : [] , show : false }

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {

    console.log('compsonentWillReceiveProps............ from Api');

     console.log(newProps)

     console.log(newProps.people.peopleReducer.people)

     var arr = newProps.people.peopleReducer.people

    console.log("new peoples state --------- ", arr)


     this.setState({ peoples:  arr  })


    console.log("new peoples state --------- ", this.state.peoples)

  }


  getpeople = () => {

    this.props.dispatch(fetchPeopleFromAPI())

  }

  render() {

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={ this.getpeople } >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Load People</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>



    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  button: {
    height: 60,
    width: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#0b7eff'
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white'
  }
});


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    people: state
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Your question consists of an entire component here and that's very broad

Comment: Can you post your component code in full to allow us see and edit directly there for a better answer

Comment: Added the missing parts in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
this.setState({
    people: newProps.people.peopleReducer.people
});
```

If you are assigning within `render` use

```
this.state.people = newProps.people.peopleReducer.people;
```

You can directly assign to state within `render` method. But if the state has to be set from other events you need to call `setState` method, which will eventually call the `render` after setting state.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to call `getPeople` function somewhere in your component

Best place to do it is

```
componentDidMount(){
   getPeople();
}
```

Then inside this `getPeople` function you are calling `this.props.fetchPeopleFromAPI`. But right now there is no mapDispatchToProps to do this.

So before the connect function if you can add

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    fetchPeopleFromAPI: () => {
      dispatch(fetchPeopleFromAPI())
    }
  }
}
```

Then at last, you can modify your `connect` and pass the newly added mapDispatchToProps.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Since you  are mapping your store state to component's props

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
    people: state.people.peopleReducer.people // Try doing the hierarchy here
  }
}
```

Thus, there will be no need for adding `componentWillReceiveProps` here at least. Instead access the people in `render` as `this.props.people` as you have already mapped them to props above.

All this is based on that your actions and reducers are working correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  let { people } = newProps.people.peopleReducer;
  this.setState({
    people 
  }); 
}
```